# Android get process output continuously

Tags: java, android, process, inputstream

I have an android process that I start. It is a getevent command. This (when ran in a console) gives continuous event occurances. I wish to collect these within an Android app. My current way of doing this will effectively collect "one off" process outputs but I can't seem to find a way of storing the continuous results from the getevent method as they occur.

The current code I have for this is the following. It works for things like "ls" but not for continuous streams such as "getevent".

```
try {
            Process chmod = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getevent -lt /dev/input/event1");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(chmod.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            reader.close();
            chmod.waitFor();
            String outputString =  output.toString();
            Log.d("output", outputString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is how I solved it.

First I created a TimerTask to log/read continuous output in a BufferReader of either a logcat or getevent. TimerTask creates new Thread, which runs in background and doesn't interfere or block other UI handlers in service class. So I believe it is safer that way.

Then I started the TimerTask from Service class in onCreate() method.

One thing is mine device was rooted, so I start with 'su' session. I believe 'sh' session is also works for non root devices.

Service class:

```
public class ServiceClassPhone extends Service {
....

private GetEventRecorder getEventRecorder;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

....

getEventRecorder= new GetEventRecorder();
getEventRecorder.start();
// (if there is any) postDelay other UI handlers in service
}
```

And GetEventRecorder class:

```
public class GetEventRecorder {


....
private static Logger mLogger = new Logger();

private GetEventRecorder mRecorder = null;
Timer timer;

// active su session
private Process mProcess;
// Byte Writer
private OutputStream mStdIn;
private DataOutputStream outputStream;
private BufferedReader br;


{
    try {
        mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(mProcess.getOutputStream());
        String comm1 = "getevent -l";
        String comm2 = "logcat -c";
        String close = "^C";
        String newLine= "\n";

        outputStream.writeBytes(comm1);
        outputStream.writeBytes(newLine);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Could not spawn su process");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void start()  {

        try {

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new GetEventRecorder.RecorderTask(), 0, 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
        }

}

public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder = null;
        timer.cancel();
    }
}



public void logGetEventData(){
    ....

}

}


    private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask {


    public RecorderTask() {}


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            String comm1 = "getevent -l";
            String comm2 = "logcat -c";
            String close = "^C";
            byte[] newLine = "\n".getBytes();

            outputStream.writeBytes(close);
            outputStream.flush();


            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mProcess.getInputStream()));
            boolean cont=true;
            String line;
            Log.d(TAG,"geteventLogs BufferedReader for continuous getevent reading... " );
            if (br!=null ) {
                Log.d(TAG,"geteventLogs BufferedReader is not null checking for readiness... ");
                if (br.ready()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BufferedReader for getevent is not null and ready");


                    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.contains("event0:")
                            && !line.contains("BufferedReader") ) {
                            ...
                            logGetEventData();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "getevent recorder error: " + e);
        }
    }
}


}
```